# How to loop record well in Android?

Tags: video, video-recording, video-conference

I need to find a procedure to record well well video which is about recording video conferences from another screen.

The length of the session is about 0.5 - 1 hour. 
The size of my memory card is 8 Gb, but I do not know if it is possible to record there with my Samsung Galaxy S4. 
I need to record sound and some quality of the video. It is enough that I can see some of the video like boundaries at least; precise accuracy not needed.

How can you loop-record videos well in basic Samsung smart-phones?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Comment: Thank you for you comment! The question how you can loop-record well, not - what can record you well video in Android! This is not about one particular software, but about the setting generally.